# Angularjs 1.5.x share data with service between components

Tags: angularjs, service, components, init, message-passing

I am fairly new to angularjs, and would like to ask a few questions.
I am working on a project where I need to get a form object from the server.  The form is a complicated tree object with many layers, and I have created 4 different components/tabs to bind to the corresponding objects.  I had created a Service to get the data.

```
angular.module('myService', ['restangular'])
        .factory('FormService', ['Restangular', '$q', function(Restangular, $q) { 

    function FormService() {
        var self = this;
        self.form = null;

        self.getForm = function getForm(id)
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (self.form !== null)
            {
                deferred.resolve(self.form);
                console.log("Cache!");
            }
            else {
                Restangular.one('form', id).get()
                  .then(function successCallback(response)
                  {
                    self.form = response;
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                    console.log("from server!");

                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                    console.log("error, cannot resolve object");
                  });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }

      return new FormService();
  }])
});
```

Then I had my components all with similar config below:

```
angular.module('page1Summary', ['formService']).component('page1Summary', {
  templateUrl: 'page1-summary/page1-summary.template.html',
  controller: ['FormService', function Page1SummaryController(FormService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    // ******* Init Params Start *********** //
    this.$onInit = function() {
      // init value when object ready
      FormService.getForm()
        .then(
          /* on success */
          function successCallback(data) {
            console.log("page1-summary init");
            ctrl.form = data;
            console.log("page1-summary got the data");
        },
          /* on error */
          function errorCallback(data)
          {
              console.log("failed to get form");
          }
      );
    }

    /* other stuff here */
 }
```

I was printing either "cache!" or "from server" on the getForm service.  So that I can figure out whether I am pulling the data from server or memory.  However, everytime I refresh, the result is different.  Sometimes, the data saved in the local variable in service, and got "cached", but sometimes, some of my pages will get the data "from server".

I would like to know what is going wrong?  I thought only the first time the service would get from server, but it seems like it is not the case.

Can someone please help me out and point out what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are caching your result into `self.form`.
`self.form` is again a variable `FormSerivce` Factory member.
It will cache the result till you do not refresh the page.
Once you refresh the page the value in `self.form` will get reset just like all the other variable in your application.

What you want is instead of caching result in `self.form`, cache it in `localstorage`.
So you can get the result back even after your page refresh.